# how to style radio button with text on it

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

It'm trying to do the effect below for the radio buttons but i'm not sure what is the best way for doing it

[image]

I've tried using css to hide buttons and when I want to check them values are not sent to the server.

I also tried using jquery like that but it also does not works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.radio').each(function () {
      $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
   });
});
```

So if somebody can tell me the best way for doing this effect.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: What's your relevant ("[MCVE]") HTML? And CSS?

Comment: what is the best way for doing it ? html and css ? jquery ?

Comment: can be styled that way with html and css only. Should be easy to find tutorials on how to do it

Comment: The 'best way' requires you to define some objective requirements, but for styling/presentation I'd suggest CSS and HTML. However, you need to show your (attempted) HTML and CSS to go along with the jQuery you've already shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to hide the input itself and use `+` and `:checked` selector to decorate the `span` sibling of the input when the input is `:checked`

```css
div {
  border-top:1px solid #A6A6A6;  
  border-bottom:1px solid #A6A6A6;  
  padding:15px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font-family:arial;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:12px;
}

span {
  color:#009ACE;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight:bold;
  transition:all .2s ease;
  font-size:14px;
}

input {
  display:none;  
}

input:checked + span {
  background:#009ACE;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Size
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" checked />
        <span>S</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" />
        <span>M</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" />
        <span>L</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="size" />
        <span>XL</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My own approach to this would be to use a styled `<form>` (and contents, obviously), making use of the `:checked` pseudo-class to style the letters:

```css
fieldset {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 0;
}

legend {
  /*
    to move the <legend> element to the beginning
    of the row containing the <label> and <input>
    elements: */
  float: left;

  /*
    to vertically centre the text of the element: */
  line-height: 2em;
}

legend ~ input[type=radio] {
  /*
    to allow the <input> elements to be visually
    removed from the page: */
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}

label {
  /*
    to clearly imply interactivity: */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: skyblue;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  /*
    to vertically centre the text:
  */
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

/*
  to style the <label> elements that are
  adjacent to a checked radio <input>: */
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Size</legend>
    <input id="sizeSmall" value="small" type="radio" name="size">
    <label for="sizeSmall">S</label>
    <input id="sizeMedium" value="medium" type="radio" name="size">
    <label for="sizeMedium">M</label>
    <input id="sizeLarge" value="large" type="radio" name="size">
    <label for="sizeLarge">L</label>
    <input id="sizeXLarge" value="xLarge" type="radio" name="size">
    <label for="sizeXLarge">XL</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```